# Do a select query on all tables of PostgreSQL database using pgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a database of around 90 schemas. In each of these schemas, I go to "Materialized Views" and go to a one of the views called, "product_visitor_view" and I create a SELECT script and I write this script and run it and see the results:

```
SELECT priority, count(*)
FROM ag_modem_01.product_visitor_view
group by priority;
```

However, I cannot do this for all 90 around schemas. Is there a way I can do this for all schemas and the results would be shown for each schema in a page and how can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare the SQL for each schema using below query.
The idea is to instead of manually writing all the query, you can use the system table **pg_matviews** which contains information about materialized views.
Once you have the list, just need to do union all between all the rows.

```
select 
string_agg('select '''||schemaname||''' as schema,priority,count(*) from '||schemaname||'.'||matviewname
           ||' group by priority '||chr(10),' Union All '||chr(10)
           )
from pg_matviews
where matviewname='product_visitor_view'
and ispopulated=true; -- to filter out Views which has not been populated
```

Take the output from this query and run it in the Querytool.

Comment: First of all thank you for responding. I ran this in query tool created by right-clicking on Schemas(91). I ran the query and I got a huge text string. I pasted the text and I received this error: ERROR:  materialized view "product_visitor_view" has not been populated HINT:  Use the REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW command. SQL state: 55000

Comment: Looks like few of your materialized views are not refreshed. You can exclude these views by applying below additional filter condition. and ispopulated=true

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly as I dreamt it.

Comment: Hello. So sorry to bother you again. What if I want to add this clause: "where market != 'hepsiburada'"? How can i achieve this in that string aggregator you wrote?

Comment: Just add that before the `group by priority` text, one thing you have to take care is for single quote.  It will look something like `  ||' where market != '''hepsiburada''' group by priority ' `